# MSDN like API for sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Quiet new to sitecore world and haven't come across any online API that looks like MSDN. Could anyone please advice if there is any such resource for sitecore development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

API documentation exists on the SDN site, for example Database.GetItem is documented http://sdn.sitecore.net/doc/api%205.0/Sitecore.Data.Database.GetItem.html

Admittedly it's the 5.0 API documentation, but kernel API methods don't change that often.

---

Try visiting the one of these official Sitecore sites:

- [Learn Sitecore](https://www.sitecore.net/)
- [Sitecore Documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/)
- [Sitecore Community](https://community.sitecore.net/)

Comment: The old ones do exist indeed, but I never foudn them useful ;)

Comment: Once you get over the basics, I've found it easier to just crack open DotPeek!

Answer (score 2):

You can download the API reference as a .chm help file, you can browse that offline in the same manner as you would MSDN.

[Sitecore CMS 6 API Reference](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Sitecore_6_API_Reference.aspx)

You will need to unblock the file to view the content: Right Click > Properties > Unblock

Answer (score 0):

There is not an online API like MSDN. But you can login to [sdn.sitecore.net](http://sdn.sitecore.net) and find a lot of documentation there.

Comment: Yep, I also noticed there are lots of PDF docos. But would be good to have online reference like MSDN which can easily be found while coding.